# Func: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Tags: scheme, racket

This function should get a function (x+2) and an integer, and return the a list with l0,ln,l1,ln-1,l2,ln-2.........l(n/2),l(n/2)+1, how can i get it right ?

what is the problem ?

```
#lang racket

(define Func (lambda(F n)
 (Merge (FuncL F 0 (quotient n 2)) (FuncR F n (+(quotient n 2) 1)))))

(define FuncL (lambda(F n k)
 (if (= n k)
  (list (F n))
  (cons (F n) (FuncL F (+ n 1) k)))))

(define FuncR (lambda(F n k)
  (if (= n k)
  (list F n)
  (cons (F n) (FuncR F (- n 1) k)))))

 (define Merge (lambda(L1 L2)
            (if (null? L1)
               (list)
               (cons (car L1) (cons (car L2) (Merge (cdr L1) (cdr L2)))))))


(define L (Func (lambda (x) (+ x 2)) 5))
(display L)
```

Comment: The order of your definitions.

Comment: but i still have a problem...

Comment: Really awesome and intuitive naming and on point naming convention there. Not possivble to mix two functions at all!

Comment: This function should get a function (x+2) and an integer, and return the a list with l0,ln,l1,ln-1,l2,ln-2.........l(n/2),l(n/2)+1, how can i get it right ?

Comment: Well.. Questions in the commens doesn't get answered. You need to EDIT your question since how it is now it's close to get close votes.

Comment: You MUST DROP EVERYTHING you're doing and rename all the methods and variables

Answer (score 0):

```
(define FuncR (lambda(F n k)
  (if (= n k)
  (list (F n)) ;; (list F n) here you miss a pair of parenthesis 
  (cons (F n) (FuncR F (- n 1) k)))))
```

You fault was, that you did NOT tested you procedures separately.

```
(define Foo (lambda (x) (+ x 2)))
(FuncR Foo 5 0)) 
--->
(7 6 5 4 3 #[compound-procedure 18 foo] 0)
```

So the mistake was easy to detect.
I think

```
(Func (lambda (x) (+ x 2)) 5) --> (2 7 3 6 4 5)
```

is the result, which you want.

I suppose, that this is a homework. What is frame?

Comment: Ill try that, that was a question from an exam, "programming languages" course, we didnt learn the basics of this